# radio button checked show div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button, html-input

I have this code:

```
<div style="padding-bottom:11px;">

<input class="radio" type="radio" value=" join our table" name="Choose:">
<label class="optionLabel"> join our table</label>

</div>
```

What I want to do is when a radio button is checked to show a div, something similar with a tooltip.

The problem is that I don't know how to detect when a radio button is checked.

Any suggestions are welcome. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect the click, or change, event on a radio input element and show a `div` in response:

```
$('input:radio').click(
    function(e){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(selectorForRelevantDivElement).show();
        }
    });
```

Or:

```
$('input:radio').change(
    function(e){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(selectorForRelevantDivElement).show();
        }
    });
```

You could also use the `on()` method, and bind to an ancestor element of the radio inputs (this is used to assign event-handling to elements created dynamically):

```
$('form').on('change click', 'input:radio', function(e){
        console.log(e.type); // shows the event, whether 'click' or 'change'
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(selectorForRelevantDivElement).show();
        }
    });
```

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: Thank you! How can I show a div only on a specific radio button  because I have 3 radio buttons

Comment: Without more information about your page it's hard to guess, I'm afraid. Though I'll post a couple of suggestions later, when I have time, if that'd be of help.

Answer (score 1):

You want the jQuery change event handler. Something like this:

```
$(".radio").change(function(e){
    // create your div here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the click event for the radioButton.. Or even the Change event..

```
$(function() {
    $('.radio').on('click', function(){
        $('.a').show();        
    });
});​
```

Check This [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/FhCZV/9/)

You can select the radioButton in many ways

```
$('.radio').on('click', function(){

$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function(){
```

[DYNAMIC ELEMENT FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/FhCZV/11/)

Comment: Thanks! But how can I be more specific because I have 3 radio button and I want to show that div only when a specific radio button is clicked

Comment: @Alecs check the updated Fiddle in the post above.. I have added classes to the divs and based on the ID of the input selected I am displaying the divs...

Comment: Thanks but the inputs in my case are generated dinamically like this: `<input <?php if( $key == 0 ){ echo "checked='checked'"; } ?> class="radio" type="radio" value="<?php echo $wpcpup_answer; ?>" name="<?php echo $wpcpup_input['label']; ?>">`

Comment: If that's the you need to add  the event handlers for the Radio Button's once they are added on to the page

Comment: Lets say you have added radio4 when you click on a button. So as soon as it is added you would just do this  $('#radio4').on('click', function(){ // Your code here })

Comment: I can't really do this because if I add #radio4 then all the radio buttons will be radio4, so I have to target them by name or by value if it's possible

Comment: I have added a new fiddle when you create a element on click of a button .. Check that out..